# Как соединить имя таблицы?

Tags: lua, table

Как соединить имя таблицы? В следующем примере нужно менять имя таблицы присвоив "х", 11 или 12:

```
tbl11 ={5,6,7}
tbl12 ={8,9,111}
x = 12
a = 'tbl'..x
print(a[3])
```

в результате должно быть 111 или 7, но не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратись к таблице через глобальную таблицу _G:

```
tbl11 ={5,6,7}
tbl12 ={8,9,111}
x = 12
a = 'tbl'..x
print(_G[a][3])
```

Comment: Но это сработает, только если таблица глобальная (что обычно плохо). Иначе нужно будет вести свой аналог словаря имён (таблицу).

Comment: @val не обязательно, можно использовать и локальную таблицу, `_G[a]` будет указывать на таблицу `a`, которая видна в данной области.

Comment: Не-а. Локальных переменных в `_G` (строго говоря, в `_ENV` с lua 5.2) нет. `_G`/`_ENV` — это не магия, `_G`/`_ENV` — просто таблица, которая подразумевается по умолчанию при отсутствии подходящей неглобальной переменной и не меняется на разных уровнях стека. `local test1 = 'hi'; print(_G['test1'])` не прокатит.

Comment: @val да, все верно, это я не там использовал `local a`

Comment: В данном примере так понимаю есть только один способ, использовать _G, или есть другие методы еще?

Comment: ну еще можно по другому организовать таблицы, все лучше чем через склейку: `local tbl = { [11]={5,6,7} , [12]={8,9,111} }  x=12 print(tbl[x][3])`